# Resource for datasheets not publicly available?

Tags: datasheet

I'm doing academic research into glucometers.  It appears every sensor/ AFE  requires an NDA to get the IC datasheet but not just an NDA, it must be one from a company intending to build thousands/ millions of glucometers.

This essentially means that academics/ startups cannot access the datasheets.

For academic papers, there is [sci-hub](https://sci-hub.mksa.top/).

Is there anything similar for datasheets?

Comment: Sometimes they'll show up on search engines. Google, Yandex, Baidu, Bing. Try searching actual full or partial part numbers.

Comment: Unfortunately making such a data sheet available requires that someone violate their NDA, so there's automatically at least a bit of sleaze involved.  The problem with freely providing a datasheet for your product is that you're not only helping engineers design the parts into their products, but you're also helping competitors see exactly what your capabilities are, and giving big hints about how to build competing products.  So if your marketing strategy is to sell to a few large-volume customers _anyway_, it makes sense to hold your data sheets tightly.

Comment: If a document is proprietary, any resources freely distributing it are illegal. Communicate directly with the manufacturers and/or work through your institution.

Comment: Not unless someone violates their NDA placing themselves at legal risk.

Comment: I am surprised that an academic would be looking for a way to break the law. What country are you in?

Comment: On the one hand, there is much that is legal that probably isn't _good_, and this could be one of them.  On the other hand, the mechanism by which most technology creators (including me) gets paid runs straight through the keeping of trade secrets.  If all of _my_ work were freely published, I would have no mechanism for getting paid, and I would have to dig ditches to feed my family -- or watch ditches being dug with technology that I created, while getting no remuneration.

Comment: @TimWescott I've worked on datasheets.  I've worked in companies where the semiconductor manufacturers fall over themselves to give free samples and sign our NDA's and I've worked in startups that have been frozen out of the market.  A datasheet is not a schematic, there's huge work that goes into bringing a design to market.  It's just big corporations flexing on the little guy.

Comment: @SeanJ - it's not "flexing on the little guy", it's just business. You buy 1 unit, you probably need the same/more support as the entity buying 1M units so it's just not worth their time. If you're at a university, use the resources available to you there (legal etc) to get in touch with companies, rather than approaching them as an individual. Most companies like the glow of working with academics as their students will buy their products in the future...

Comment: I wouldn't say they are flexing on the little guy, I would say they are optimizing their return in investment. Why should a tech support person spend time understanding your needs, then working with their attorney to write an NDA that covers your needs, negotiating the NDA with your organization, conveying the datasheets to you, addressing any unanswered questions you will have because the datasheet is half-baked because the product is actually tuned to each million-unit application when paying customers commit to a product.  Then enforcing the NDA if you violate it.  What's in it for them?

Comment: I am not sure what is the argument here. The datasheets are the property of the company. If they do not wish to release them for free, it is their right. Looking for illegal ways to obtain someone's else  property is that is - illegal, period.

Comment: Why do you assume that an NDA "cuts out academics entirely, no entry"? Don't assume that you are the only academic on this site, many of us have the same desire to do research. Have you tried asking the companies directly and offering to sign their NDA, or is your intent to do something that would harm the companies?

Comment: Companies have no incentive to have individuals to sign NDAs, so make it inherently beneficial to the company.

Comment: All - (a) FYI this was flagged for moderators to close/delete, based on a claim that the question is trying to do something illegal. However, for reasons explained in [this Meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94465) from the [SE FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931), if mods start acting on such IP-related claims, it can create much bigger problems for SE - see that link. Laws are not the same everywhere and mods are not lawyers. (b) Comments making comparisons to topics like slavery, and using terms like "close minded", have been deleted. Remember: *Be Nice*.

Comment: [continued] (c) Further mod actions might follow, not because of the subject of the question, but because of the off-topic and unproductive points in some comments. Remember that as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756), comments are primarily for clarifying the question, and *constructive* criticism of the question *that helps the author to improve it*. Not for answering it, or debate, or *ad hominem* arguments, or other wider criticism. Thanks. (Of course voting etc. can be used, according to the conscience and belief of site members, as usual.)

Answer (score 2):

This is what you would do if your business was at risk of cheap knockoffs from IP theft.

I assume you have tried Google Scholar and Microsoft Academic for research on what has been done already regarding accuracy with respect to international standards.

Researchgate is a good way to request for relevant information and compare your goals with what already has been done and include how you can help in return.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/331741037_Accuracy_and_precision_of_four_main_glucometers_used_in_a_Sub-Saharan_African_Country_a_cross-sectional_study

Comment: Not sure if that always improves revenue stream if you already have R&D staff.

Answer (score 2):

You can ask the manufacturer or distributor if there is an academic program, or something similar to provide such information to startups. I did once, long ago, and was provided with typewritten data for a new CPU, on the basis that they could provide no further support to an individual.

Of course, they can say no.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is finding a **finished product** containing the glucometer you are looking for and then desolder it or, if that product is an open hardware/source product, you can program it.

---

Try the following links:

https://patient-innovation.com/post/711

https://www.seeedstudio.com/Open-source-Arduino-blood-glucose-meter-shield-p-4813.html

Comment: sorry, I'm only looking at the IC components.  I know the component but can't get access to the datasheet.